# phantom js not injecting javascript until end of loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, phantomjs

I am attempting to create dummy webpages in an attempt to test load balance on a server, I loop through 100 instances of a pages element and create it accordingly. I am having difficulty when injecting JS it is not doing it for all bar the last in the loop.

```
for(var i=0; i<instances; i++) {
    pages.push(require('webpage').create());
}

console.log('Loading web page');
for(var i in pages) {
    pages[i].customHeaders = {
        'X-Forwarded-For': '192.111.111.'+i
    };
    var ip = '192.111.111.'+i;
    var mac = "00:00:00:00:00:"+i;
    var serial = '000000000'+i;

    console.log("Loading " + url + " in page " + i);
    pages[i].onInitialized = function() {
    if(!pages[i].injectJs("amino/VideoDisplay.js")) {
        console.log("Can not include script 'VideoDisplay.js'");
        phantom.exit(1);
    }
    if(!pages[i].injectJs("amino/TVI.js")) {
        console.log("Can not include script 'TVI.js'");
        phantom.exit(1);
    }
    if(!pages[i].injectJs("amino/PVR.js")) {
        console.log("Can not include script 'PVR.js'");
        phantom.exit(1);
    }
    if(!pages[i].injectJs("amino/CEC.js")) {
        console.log("Can not include script 'CEC.js'");
        phantom.exit(1);
    }
    if(!pages[i].injectJs("amino/Browser.js")) {
        console.log("Can not include script 'Browser.js'");
        phantom.exit(1);
    }
    if(!pages[i].injectJs("amino/AVMedia.js")) {
        console.log("Can not include script 'AVMedia.js'");
        phantom.exit(1);
    }
    if(!pages[i].injectJs("amino/AudioControl.js")) {
        console.log("Can not include script 'AudioControl.js'");
        phantom.exit(1);
    }
    if(!pages[i].injectJs("amino/ASTB.js")) {
        console.log("Can not include script 'ASTB.js'");
        phantom.exit(1);
    }
    if(!pages[i].injectJs("amino/AminoGeneric.js")) {
        console.log("Can not include script 'AminoGeneric.js'");
        phantom.exit(1);
    }

};

pages[i].viewportSize = 'width: 1280, height: 720';
    pages[i].settings.userAgent = 'Opera/9.80 (Linux sh4 ; U;  Amino; en) Presto/2.5.21 Version/10.30';
    pages[i].open(url, function () { 
    pages[i].evaluate(function(ip, mac, serial) {
        ASTB.IpAddress = ip;
        ASTB.MacAddress = mac;
        ASTB.Serial = serial
    }, ip, mac, serial);
    });
}
```

Any Ideas, I am getting errors saying the ASTB variables are undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're falling into the closure trap. When you have an anonymous function that references a loop variable, it is lexically bound to the value of that variable within the loop. So when the loop variable changes, the value that the anonymous function closes over also changes, since it points to that exact same variable. The callback to `.evaluate` is asynchronous as well, so it runs after the loop has completed, at which point `i` points to the last element. You can force a scope like so, using another function:

```
(function(i) {

   page[i].evaluate(...);

})(i);
```

Or you could call another function:

```
evaluatePage(page, i);

...

function evaluatePage(page, i) {
    page[i].evaluate(...);
}
```

Comment: Im strugling a bit here, I understand where your coming from however i tried both ways and still getting no further. `pages[i].open(url, function (status, i) { console.log(status)(function (i) {
    console.log(i);
    pages[i].evaluate(function(ip, mac, serial) {
        ASTB.IpAddress = ip;
 ASTB.MacAddress = mac;  
        ASTB.Serial = serial
    }, ip, mac, serial);
})(i);
});`